# Match text children in div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
    aaaa
    <span>bbbb</span>
    cccc
    <span>dddd</span>
    eeee
</div>
```

How can I use JQuery to match the `[aaaa, cccc, eeee]` elements? I've attempted

```
$('div > :not(span)') 
$('div:not(span)') 
$('div').not('span')
```

But they all returned an empty array.